# How can I remove the border around the form?

Tags: html, css, forms

How can I remove the border around the form?
[image: Border]

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the border to none in order to do this go to your css file and enter this code in the borders properties.

```
border:none;
```

Hope I could help you!

Answer (score -1):

This is simple example how you can do it with using

`style="border:0px;"`
or
`border:none;`

```
<form>
  <p>Ordinary input field with box outline:</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Something">
  <p>Input field without outline:</p>
  <input style="border:0px;" type="text" class="no-outline" placeholder="Enter Something">
</form>
```